# Nuxt apollo smart query is called twice. What happens under the hood?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-server, vue-apollo

I use nuxt with nuxt-apollo in SSR mode. It seems smart query are called two times in SSR and one more in front. If I do that:

```
import Post from '~/apollo/queries/Post' // Post.gql file

export default {
apollo: {
    post: {
        query() {
           console.log('Post', Post)
           return Post
        }
    }
...
```

In the terminal and the devtools console, each one show two logs (devtools with `nuxt:ssr` tag) like if the query function is called twice. In devtools console, there is also one more log wihtout `nuxt:ssr` tag like if the query is called one more time in front. I think this last is normal, but there is no reason for two times in SSR...

I can reproduce that in a stackoverflow code snippet, so I created a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-apollo-smart-query-bug-7p7ni).

Did you see this behavior? Do you know what happens under the hood? Bug??

Answer (score 1):

One of the results is retrieved by cache
You can get rid of the duplication by disabling the cache in the fetchPolicy by Apollo

```
new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  defaultOptions: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
  }
})
```

And here's the `refetch` option for [Smart Query](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/blob/master/docs/api/smart-query.md#setoptions)

```
this.$apollo.queries.users.setOptions({
  fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
})
```

Comment: No. Query is always called twice. And worst, I got `[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.` everywhere :/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same behavior on my end. So far I can see the issue is caused by smart queries not populating the apollo client cache when prefetched on the server.

Thus the query is executed a second time on the client.

I am able to workaround this issue by disabling the prefetch and additionally use the `asyncData` hook.

```
import Post from '~/apollo/queries/Post'

export default {
    apollo: {
        post: {
            prefetch: false,
            query() {
                console.log('Post', Post)
                return Post
            }
        }
    },
    async asyncData(app) {
        const {data: {post}} = await app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
            query: Post
        });

        return {post};
    }
}
```

Please note that there is currently an open issue fixing another cache related bug: https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/pull/336

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem. In my case, I accidentally put a `<body>`-tag instead of a `<div>`-tag in my /layouts/default.vue file.**

This problem was also indicated in the console of the browser by

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
> server-rendered content.

In your case it may be another html tag which causes the mismatch between client-side and server-side rendering.

Comment: You helped me get through the day!